# Run init function after saving data in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, init, kivymd

I am creating a app that save teacher data and allow us to create time table. But a problem arrived. Even after saving teacher data in MySQL it doesn't seen in time table spinner.Saved teacher data only seen after again running the program.
Here is my code.py file

```
class Teacher_detail_screen(Screen):
    class Mypopup(Popup):      
        def submit_click(self,name,last,sub):# this is the teacher data saving function.
            mydb = sql.connect(
                host = "localhost", 
                user = "root",
                password = "rohit",
                database="school_db"
                )
            c = mydb.cursor()
            c.execute(f'insert into data values("{name.text}","{last.text}","{sub.text}")')
            mydb.commit()
            name.text=""
            last.text=""
            sub.text=""    
    pass    
class Class_time_table(Screen):
    class Stack(StackLayout):
        def b1_clicked(self,value):
            b1.text=f'{value}'
        def __init__(self,**kwarge): # this function runs defore saving teacher data in MySQL. 
            super().__init__(**kwarge)
            mydb = sql.connect(
            host = "localhost", 
            user = "root",
            password = "rohit",
            database="school_db"
            )
            c = mydb.cursor()
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
            record=[c.fetchall()]
            for s in record:
                global b1 
# in this spinner I want data from MySQL to be seen
                b1=Spinner(text="1",size_hint=(.141,.14),values=(f"{a[2]}({a[0][0]}{a[1][0]})"for a in s))
                self.add_widget(b1)
                b1.bind(on_text=lambda:self.b1_clicked(b1.text))
```

kv file

```
<Mypopup>
    title:" Add Teacher's Detail"
    auto_dismiss:False
    size_hint:0.6,0.8
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
    background:''
    FloatLayout:
        MDIconButton:
            icon:"arrow-left"
            pos_hint: {'x': 0,'y': .988888}
            on_press:root.dismiss()
        MDTextField:
            id:name
            hint_text:"First Name" 
            multiline:False
            pos_hint:{'x':.1 , 'y':.81 }
            size_hint: .6,.15
        MDTextField:
            id:last
            hint_text:"Last Name"
            multiline:False
            pos_hint:{'x':.1 , 'y':.7 }
            size_hint:  .6,.15
        MDTextField:
            id:sub
            hint_text:"Subject"
            multiline:False
            pos_hint:{'x':.1, 'y':.6 }
            size_hint: .6, .15
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text:"submit"
            id:submit
            pos_hint:{'x':.1 , 'y':.25}
            size_hint:(.07,.06 )
            on_press: 
                root.submit_click(name,last,sub)
            on_release: root.dismiss()
                
<Teacher_detail_screen>:
    id: teacher_Detail
    name:"teacher_Detail"
<Class_time_table>:
    id:class_time_table
    name:"class_time_table"
    
    Stack:
       spacing:"10dp"
```

In py file **class Mypopup(Popup)** is the data saving class and **class Stack(StackLayout)** is the time table class where I want the saved data to seen on pressing spinner.
But the init function run defore saving the teacher data.
Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Try trimming your code as much as possible keeping it minimal and reproducible one.

Comment: Now see it I have shorten the code

Comment: This version is **not** a [**minimal reproducible**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one.

Comment: I can not short my code more than that pls give me the solution of problem  in the code